# Dreamhost SVN Server Error: E175002

Tags: apache, svn, dreamhost

I tried googling this but I haven't come up with anything. I set up an SVN server using Dreamhost's system and it said everything was created successfully. But now when I try to import (note that I am replacing mysite.com with my actual site):

svn import MySource http://svn.mysite.com/myproject -m "Initial import" --username paul

I get an error:
**svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.mysite.com/myproject'
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://svn.mysite.com/myproject'**

What is wrong?

Comment: Unable to connect - can you hit that url in a browser? If not, then nothing's listening...

Comment: When I go to http://svn.mysite.com/myproject in a browser, a username/password dialog box pops up. I type in myinfo and get a 500 internal server error page. And at the bottom: Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Check the server's error logs. it'll have details about what caused the 500.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in the /home/user/logs/mysite.com or /home/user/logs/svn.mysite.com directories. Something must be wrong. :(

Comment: Look at the system-wide httpd.conf where you site's setup is specified, find out from that 'uber' .conf file where the logs are going.